# SPManagedObject creating "duplicate symbol" error

Tags: simperium

Simperium is giving me the following error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol [REDACTED]/Simperium.framework/Simperium(SPManagedObject.o) and [OTHER-REDACTED]/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SPManagedObject.o
```

Any idea what causes this duplicate symbol bug? (I put REDACTED in there so it's not specific to my app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see this error if you accidentally auto-generate .h and .m files for the `SPManagedObject` entity in the model editor. You should only auto-generate files for your own entities, since Simperium.framework provides the `SPManagedObject` class for you.